# Strange behaviour playing with array/object/console on different browsers

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, console.log

I was playing with some basic operation in javascript, in particular with arrays, and I found out something pretty weird:
let's declare

```
var myVar = [1,2,3];
```

Now if I check the `typeof myVar` I get of course `"object"` as result.

**Ok, now my first question**

**1)** I can add a dynamic property to `myVar` (obviously just for this test), such as `myVar.test = 'test'`,  because `myVar` is an object (even if `myVar` is an array) and in JavaScript it's possible to add dynamic properties to objects, right?

Now after `myVar.test` is declared I noticed some differences between Chrome, Safari and Firefox JavaScript console.

If in Chrome (or Node console) I trigger `console.log(myVar)` I get `[1, 2, 3, test: "test"]`, but in Firefox, Safari and also in JsBin with the same command I get `[1, 2, 3]` as result.

But if I execute in all these browsers this:

```
for(var k in myVar){
  console.log(k,myVar[k]);
}
```

I get all the keys with the respective values:
    `0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, test -> test`

**Therefore my second question:**

**2)** This result is due to the fact I'm doing something forced in the language so the console.log is not working properly in some browsers when try to print `myVar`?

Here a simple recap: http://jsbin.com/risobewazu/edit?html,js,console,output

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `console.log()` show general info as per the object. None of `console.log()`, `console.dir()` or `console.info()` is standardized. So there  might be some differences in implementation. Try `console.dir()` for a more detailed display.

Comment: Yes, with console.dir() I get all the infos, dynamic properties included. Thanks @Redu